# SwiftUI - Items not showing in list when navigating from Form

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a reusable multi-select, so I'm messing around with views to achieve it

```swift
protocol MultiSelectProtocol: Identifiable {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct MultiSelect<T: MultiSelectProtocol>: View {

    var items: [T]
    @Binding var selectedItems: [T]

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            List(items) { item in
                Button(action: {
                    print(item)
                }, label:{
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wrapping my list with a Form View because I want it to look like the default SwiftUI Picker and I'll access to it with a NavigationLink like this

```swift
Form {
  NavigationLink(destination: MultiSelect<ContactType>(
      items: contactTypesViewModel.contactTypes,
      selectedItems: $selectedItems
  )) {
      Text("Contact Types")
  }
}
```

But when I navigate to the selector the items are not showing, I tried to wrap my form view with a navigation view and then the elements are showing, but the navigation bar is duplicated.

This is how I access the form

```
TabView
├── Other Views
└── List with add Button (Navigation View)
    └── Form View
        └── MultiSelect
```

Do I need to do something with the parent TabView or Parent Navigation View? or Do You know why the items are not shown?

Sorry if my english is not that good

Thank you

Comment: Works fine here, with simple replicated code. Tested with Xcode 11.4. So the issue, I assume, in using code, note here.